# Google Chrome color picker isn't responding

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Google Chrome color picker isn't responding. I tried  re-installing and resetting Chrome. How can this be resolved?

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome, see https://crbug.com/851311, and try resetting devtools settings.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

"Reset devtools" doesn't fix the issue. I am not entirely sure what the exact cause of this bug is, but the only fix available will need to be done in an update. I could not find it in the code itself, although I didn't spend much time looking.

The main issue is that **when your dev tools are docked to the bottom of the window, then the color picker will not show**. It will load though, but the interface wont show. More than likely it is either in the wrong layer, or has some issue with its actual display, as no errors are thrown.

Anyway, **the reason resetting dev tools works is because the default setting is to dock the dev tools to the right side of the screen** (presumably, their testing showed most users use a wide screen, multiple screen, setup; as a result, there is room on the side of the screen).

If you, like me, use dev tools docked to the bottom, then in order to see the color picker, you need to change the dev tool temporarily to be docked to the right side of the screen. This does not require the settings to be reset, just simply change the docking position.

Comment: This got the color picker working for me. I'm on Win10, using `Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and the issue is still present, namely, that if dev tools is docked to the bottom, the color picker UI does not work.

Comment: This solution still works for Chrome 83 in June 2020.

Comment: Thanks! works for me too, in the right or in the left. Version 86.0.4240.198 / Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 15):

if your color picker not working on your mouse pointer, then you have to change your display settings, if your display settings are at scale 125 or more then your color picker won't work in any of the browsers, if you **change your display setting to 100%** your color picker will automatically start working

Comment: Any resolution to this except changing display setting?

Comment: No ankur, I didn't find it yet.

Comment: @Mandeepsingh that was the exact issue i had. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue on Chrome 108.0.5359.98 on Arch for a long time now.

The problem was fixed by simply unchecking one of the experiments in `DevTools` - `Settings` - `Experimets` - `Enable color picking outside the browser window`.

Comment: Thanks! It works on version 109 / Ubuntu 22.

Comment: Had the same issue for the longest time for Chrome on my Debian system, this did the trick

Answer (score 8):

Changing the window size brings back the color picker. If the window is full screen size, get out of full screen size.

**The solution that worked for me is:**

- Get out of full screen mode (Un-maximize window).
- Reduce the window size, specially the width.

Docking the dev-tools to right side, Scaling the display, Lowering display resolution also brings the color-picker back as all of these affects the browser window size. Hopefully this bug will be addressed soon.

Comment: This is the only solution that's a solution.

Comment: This solved it for me...but the solution is so unintuitive. This behavior MUST be a bug - it never happened to me until July 5, 2021, and I've been using this feature for years.

Answer (score 5):

Open the inspect elements -> go to settings -> Preferences -> scroll down to the end you will see button **"Restore defaults and reload"** -> click on it and it will work[image]

Comment: oh, thank you!!!! Nothing else besides this worked for me. I have been looking everywhere

Answer (score 1):

scale your display settings to 100 % and again re scale to 125%(recommended).

Answer (score 0):

For me chaning the Devtools zoom size worked not the webpage size.
**Ctrl + Mouse** wheel zooms in or out on the dev tools dock.

[image: Zoomed Dock]
[image: Zoomed Dock]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple. You are unable to use the color picker because **you have enabled the mobile view or any other device view**
and, you got the answer, you just need to **close the device toolbar** and you are good to go.
Hope that works

[image: Disable the device toggle button]