# Chrome DevTools color picker eyedropper isn't working

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, color-picker

I have this Chrome DevTools color picker issue where the eyedropper is not working when I change the dock position to **bottom**. The default setting is on the right side and the color picker eyedropper is working fine but not when I change the position. Is there any setting for this? Cause I am unable to find it from DevTools settings.

**1. Default Color Picker Eyedropper - dock to right**

[image]

**2. Dock to bottom**

[image]

Comment: There's no setting. It's a bug, but I can't reproduce it here. You can report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: @EatenTaik I just got hit by this bug. Did you report it?

Comment: @Leo Yeah I did report it but they can't produce the error like how I told them. It worked after I re-installed my chrome but sometimes it will still occur then I'll just refresh the page and it will work again.

Comment: @EatenTaik Thanks. I have seen quite a few strange bugs when Chrome is about to update itself. But this bug seems to happen at any time. I will keep in mind to refresh.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue for years now. Eyedropper doesn't work when:
1. devtools are docked to bottom 2. windows 10 screen scaling are set to 125% (if one change screen scaling it's working)
could anyone report the bug because I'm kinda not registered?

Comment: @Hebe I think it's better if you register and report it yourself if the error is still occur cause they will collect the information of the device and the version of chrome that you use.

Comment: @Eaten Taik all right, do you have this issue too?

Comment: @Hebe I have this issue too but not all the time like before (before re-install chrome) like what I mentioned in my previous comment, if I refresh, it will work again. Not sure if refreshing work for you though.

Comment: @Eaten Taik for me it works like once after each chrome update. Then something happens and it doesn't work. If I change screen scaling to 100% it works though.

Comment: i have the same issue too, is there even a temporary solution

Comment: happens intermittently to me. Haven't been able to find any pattern or resolution yet. Came looking up for a solution.

Comment: btw I've repoted this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1130362

Comment: they seem to finally fix this
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1130362
looks like will be available at chrome 92

Comment: they updated colorpicker in chrome 103. it's working and it can catch color outside window!

Answer (score 6):

Go to settings > experiments > and uncheck "Enable color picking outside the browser window" this should solve the problem. It worked for me.

Comment: thank you, this has been driving me nuts with multi monitors

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, for me it happens only when I use **multiple screens**

So if I have tab in the left screen and use Chrome DevTools color picker eyedropper isn't working but when I move the browser tab in to the right screen and started working again.

Also you can check this answer for a similar issue here: [Google Chrome color picker isn't responding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969567/google-chrome-color-picker-isnt-responding/53332075)

Answer (score 0):

This might help solve your problem it's quite simple. Make sure the edit 'pencil' looking icon located right next to the circle is activated in your Chrome DevTools. Clicking on it triggers the color picker hover tool on and off.